# How to run dynamically generated cmd script with admin rights from C++ application

Tags: c++, windows

I need to run cmd script that is generated during program execution.

I tried using system(…) command however it seems it is not possible to get admin rights for script launched that way.

I tried using ShellExecute(…) however it seems it can run only already existing files - I can't pass string that exist only during program execution to ShellExecute. I want to avoid creating temporary files.

Here is part of my code

```
std::string cmdScript =
        "cd %" + path_third_party_app + "%\\bin &&"
        "curl \"https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py \" -o \"get-pip.py\" && "
        //...and so on
        "pause \n"
int res = system(cmdScript.c_str());
```

This script works only if it is called with admin rights (to test I tried calling this script by launching it manually with admin rights and it works), but I can't find a way to force it to be run with admin rights by application, and I don't want if possible writing yet another band-aid solution.

Is there any other way to do this that I missed?

Comment: It needs admin rights to execute command in the folder that I needs it to be executed

Comment: Why don't you use Python/pip's API instead of shelling it?

Comment: Run the process with parameters. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652210/kill-my-process-if-the-other-process-is-killed/49652550#49652550)