# Open a file containing a variable name

Tags: c++, file, system

I have the following code:

```
string name;
getline(cin,name);
ofstream foldercreator(name + "folder.bat");
foldercreator << "if not exist \"" << name << "\" mkdir " << name << endl;
foldercreator << "exit";
```

The problem is, that

```
string batname = "start " + name + "folder";
system(batname);
```

```
system("start " + name + "folder");
```

doesn't work either.

The only problem is, that it cannot open the file.

Comment: system is a  `C` function. Use `system( batname.data() );`. In any case - I think your are looking for [boost process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652210/kill-my-process-if-the-other-process-is-killed/49652550#49652550)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::string::c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to obtain a pointer to C string from `std::string`.

```
string batname = "start " + name + "folder";
system(batname.c_str());
```

```
system(("start " + name + "folder").c_str());
```